# How to open JQuery dialog in child user control in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have an `aspx` page which has one child user control. In both `aspx` and child user control, I am using jquery dialog.

While using jquery dialog alone in the `aspx` file, it will work; but when I try to use in child user control the jquery dialog in `aspx` stops opening.

I cannot understand only putting jquery dialog in child user control it affect `aspx` jquery dialog.

Comment: Tried to improve question

Comment: I solved it..I am using same id for dialog div.Both in aspx as well as child user control. Id must be unique.